# FSMountServerVolumeSync parameter objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I'm just starting Objective C after being pampered with Applescript, and I can't seem to get FSMountServerVolumeSync to work.  This is going to seem like a completely beginner question, but **how do you pass a parameter from a variable to this action**?
Let me explain:
I want to take a variable called ***username and set it to the username** in this action. I would also like to do this to ***url and url**. Is there any way someone could show me a sample of how to set this up, from an absolute beginner standpoint?
I am currently reading through tutorials and etc., but I would like to get this section of code done even if I don't exactly understand what I'm doing. ;)
Thanks in advance!

[edit] Here's what I've got so far:

```
- (IBAction)signin:(id)sender{

NSString * user = @"myusername";
NSString * password = @"mypassword";
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"smb://123.456.789.0"];
NSURL * mountDir = [NSURL URLWithString: @"/Students"];

OSStatus FSMountServerVolumeSync (
                                  CFURLRef url, 
                                  CFURLRef mountDir, 
                                  CFStringRef user, 
                                  CFStringRef password, 
                                  FSVolumeRefNum *null, 
                                  OptionBits flags);


}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What have you tried and where are you having problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These aren't dumb questions at all.

Remember that CFStringRef and CFURLRef are *toll free bridged*, which means that the Objective C equivalents are NSString and NSURL.  All you need to do is cast.

```
- (IBAction)signin:(id)sender{

    NSString * user = @"myusername";
    NSString * password = @"mypassword";
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"smb://123.456.789.0"];
    NSURL * mountDir = [NSURL URLWithString: @"/Students"];
    OptionBits flags = 0;
    OSStatus err = FSMountServerVolumeSync (
                                      (CFURLRef) url, 
                                      (CFURLRef) mountDir, 
                                      (CFStringRef) user, 
                                      (CFStringRef) password, 
                                      NULL, 
                                      flags);

    if(err != noErr)
        NSLog( @"some kind of error in FSMountServerVolumeSync - %ld", err );
}
```

See what I mean so far?

[Here is some Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010677-SW1) on toll free bridged types.

Comment: When I use this, it doesn't give any errors, but I do get unused variable messages... is this normal, because the NSString isn't being used but the CFString is? Or did I do something wrong? Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Depends on where the "unused variable" warnings are coming from. Follow your code and if there's a variable that is being assigned but never referenced, there's no need to have it in your function.

Comment: I hate to keep asking questions, but the variables I'm getting this message for are url, username, password, and mountDir. I'm casting them in the line before I run OSStatus FSMountServerVolumeSync.  Shouldn't they be used?

Comment: Edit your original question to show how you're calling the code now and I'll edit my answer to get rid of your warnings.

Comment: and I updated my answer. You were declaring variables within the FSMountServerVolumeSync call itself.  If you use my changes, you'll be properly casting. I hope this helps!

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I am trying to the do the same, but I'm getting an error message "Implicit declaration of function 'FSMountServerVolumeSync' is invalid in C99 ", I have tried importing <objc/runtime.h> and <stdlib.h> but had no luck. Can you please help me here.

Comment: @SarimSidd if you're still having trouble, you might need to ask a new question on [so], as I don't think your problem is all that related.  And when you do enter in a new question, make sure to note whether you are using .cpp or .mm extensions to your files or?